# App works normally but crashes on clicking logout button

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, locationmanager, smsmanager

I am new to android,application is crashing when i click logout button.I am not understanding why.

I released the mp player resources but still it crashes.

For logout button

```
if(view==logoutbtn)
        {
            if (mp.isPlaying()) { mp.stop();mp.release();}
            firebaseAuth.signOut();
            finish();
            Intent intent=new Intent(ProfileActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

And the function which runs on the current activity is

```
request.setInterval(5000);
client.requestLocationUpdates(request, new LocationCallback() {
                        @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
                        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                            Location location = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                            if (location != null) {


                                play_ringtone();
                                play_flashlight();
                                send_location_message(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());


                            }
                        }
                    }, null);
```

Logcat when i run activity is:

```
W/MessageQueue: Handler (android.telephony.PhoneStateListener$1) {ba9c4a5} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.telephony.PhoneStateListener$1) {ba9c4a5} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
```

And the sms function is

```
private void send_location_message(Double latitude,Double longitude)
    {
        String msg = "Emergency!!\n\nLocation\n\n"+"https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query="+latitude+","+longitude ;
        for (int i = 0; i < emergency_phones.size(); i++)
        {
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(emergency_phones.get(i), null, msg, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Message Sent To  "+emergency_phones.get(i)+"  "+latitude+" "+longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: copy the logcat

Comment: Can you add crash logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. enclose the mp.isPlaying() in Try catch to avoid null pointer exception...
2. stop the **request** object used in request.setInterval() object too in onDestroy
3. release or **unregister** the location receiver in OnDestroy as i can see you using client. requestLocationUpdates , because even though your activity is stopped the broadcast receiver will still be there and with new location update it will run the code inside , hence its always necessary to stop those threads and BroadCastReceivers

   4. that error log is of Telephony and could be outside your app and not related...